# is GoogleMaps using only public Apis?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I heard that Google is using only PublicApi's for their apps. However I supect this to be wrong if I have a look at the official "GoogleMaps" App.
In GoogleMaps V2 there is only a "setMyLocationEnabled" Method. It shows a blue dot (with accuracy) but WITHOUT a Direction. There seems to be NO Api to do the same, and you have to emulate all the behavior (e.g. register LocationListener, place a Location Marker drawable, handle bearing and rotation correctly and click Events on the "myLocation" Button).

Same applies to Marker Windows. If you set a Title to a Marker it is shown automatically on Click and you can additionally show an "InfoWindow" (which is basically a layout rendered as bmp, so no Click-Events, Scrolling etc).

In The official App there is a Window coming from the bottom of the Screen, expandable, clickable and nice looking. You are able to emulate this with much effort, too, but again no public API for it.

Next is the Master/Detail Layout Flow of the official App. I cannot get it to work, because the Maps is eating all Events (no chance to apply an OnTouchListener to the GoogleMap object.

So my question: 
Is google really using public API's ONLY and implemented any GoogleMaps feature around it, or is it just using private API's? Am I just lazy or is it just a crappy API that really could give the user more freedom?

Comment: are they 100% using the public API, probably not since the my location icon is completely different along with the infowindows that you saw. its probably a mixture of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps application doesn't use Google Maps Android API v2. What was meant by public APIs was probably Directions, Places, etc.